# Dividing an svg line art based on the intersections or common points?

Tags: python, svg, image-processing, vector, path

I'm working on a project where a provided image will be converted into line art and then will be converted into step-by-step paths for showing to the user. Finally, I'll convert the svg into gcode for a 2D plotter. I was able to create the line art using OpenCV and converted the line art into an SVG file and save it. But I'm not sure how to convert the paths into different steps.
For example, the image provided is the letter 'A'. The line art will be converted into the following steps:

1. First draw the '/' line.
2. Then draw the '\' line.
3. Finally, draw the '-' in the middle.

So basically, I want to create 3 separate svgs for those 3 steps. Any guidelines or helps related to this will be appreciated.

Comment: well, there's no substitute for learning SVG path syntax. It may look intimidating, but after some practise, you'll be parsing this in your head: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You said that you were able to create line art and save to SVG. So what more do you want ?